# Can I make Kivy apps with OpenGL 1?

Tags: kivy

The title says it all. Can I build and/or run Kivy apps on computers with videocards supporting no more than OpenGL 1.x ?

Comment: The landing page http://kivy.org/#home says, "The graphics engine is built over OpenGL ES 2".
So no, you can't. Most modern hardware even 4 years old phones and 7+ year old intel desktops Have openGL E.S. 2.0 support.

Comment: I know, but the one I'm targetting doesn't :(

Comment: PS My Intel integrated Graphics has exactly 7 years, and OpenGL 1.4

Comment: Are you using Linux with an Intel GMA (i915)? If so, you can probably fix this easily: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19607/how-to-enable-opengl-2-0-and-webgl-on-gma-3150

Comment: No, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Our graphics engine is built to use modern OpenGL, not the old one. We have no plans for that, and will never do it in the future. If you want to target very old hardware, use another toolkit :)

Comment: yeah, started it using tkinter.